# Usage of word "In future" or "In the future"

Tags: word-choice, dialect

Is it correct to use the word "In Future" or "In the future" in below statement:

> **In future**, will bring into practice using ABC Report directly from the system as soon as all balances will match with suppliers

Answer (score 7):

From https://jakubmarian.com/in-the-future-vs-in-future-in-british-and-american-english/:

> “**Future**” can be either an adjective or a noun. When used as an adjective, it doesn’t take any article itself; it is preceded by the article of the noun it modifies. Of course, the logic stays the same even after the preposition “**in**”, which is probably the most confusing case for non-native speakers:
>
> - I would like to address this issue in future articles.

---

> The phrase “**in (the) future**” has two meanings. When it means “**at a future point in time**”, it is used with the definite article:
>
> - I would like to move to Spain in the future. (**correct**)
> - I would like to move to Spain in future. (**wrong**)
>
> However, when it means “**from now on**”, there is a divide between American English and British English. An American would still say “**in the future**”, as in the previous case, whereas a Brit would likely say “**in future**” *(with no article).* Thus, “**from now on, please, be more careful**” could be rephrased as:
>
> - In future, please, be more careful. (**British English**)
> - In the future, please, be more careful. (**American English**)
>
> If you speak American English, you don’t have to care about the distinction. However, if you speak British English, using “**in future**” instead of “**in the future**” can completely change the meaning of a sentence. Compare:
>
> - Human beings will live on the Moon **in the future**. *(Human beings will live on the Moon at some point in the future.)*
> - Human beings will live on the Moon **in future**. *(**British English only**) (Human beings will live on the Moon from now on.)*

Answer (score 4):

When you want to mean "at a future point in time ", You should use " in the future ".

1) I will hit you in the future. ( I will hit you at a  future point in time)

But it has another meaning which is "from now on ". Here there is a difference between AmE and BrE. AmE speakers use "in the future " with this [from now on] meaning.  But BrE speakers use "in future ".

2) In future, please,  take care of yourself. [BrE]

3) In the future, please,  take care of yourself. [AmE]